# MSBuild throws 'name too long' on project if called from Jenkins but not CMD

Tags: msbuild, jenkins

If I run the following command manually everything compiles fine.

```
cd D:\Jenkins\[redacted]\Api>
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /property:Configuration=Release Api.sln
```

If I run the same command (copy/paste) from Jenkins MSBuild gives me the following error for one of my projects

```
"D:\Jenkins\[Redacted]\Logic\[Redacted].Api2.Logic.csproj" (default target) (26) ->
(GenerateSatelliteAssemblies target) -> 
  ALINK : error AL1061: Cannot set option 'description' because 'The file name is too long. '
```

Why does the MSBuild work when running through the CMD but not via Jenkins? It doesn't look like a permissions issue and only one project out of many that hasn't been touched in months breaks.

Even the error message is a little odd - There is no description in the assemblyinfo and there are much longer file names that compile without issues in the solution.

What could be causing this? The best I could find is this http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728795/error-al1061-when-building-satellite-assemblies-with-long-names which was of no use.