# TFS Build fails

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

After installing .NET framework 4.5 in the build server, TFS build is failing as we are getting an error (ALINK: Cannot set option 'company'), Before that the builds where working fine. I have tried everything but still it fails please help me in resolving this.

[image: Getting the following error]

Comment: error msg is very explicit.

Comment: It looks like a known issue (although it appears to be with the Beta: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728795/error-al1061-when-building-satellite-assemblies-with-long-names)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317575/msbuild-throws-name-too-long-on-project-if-called-from-jenkins-but-not-cmd

Answer (score 0):

A file name longer than 260 characters was passed to Al.exe. Choose a file name with fewer characters or a shorter path, or rename the file.

Reference:  http://www.alchemysoftware.com/livedocs/Knowledgewell/alchemy_catalyst/standard_support/troubleshooting/alink__error_al1026.htm

If the log tab on the build output in TFS is clicked, each of the before/after properties of the build steps can be seen. Review the paths being used for any custom build steps, and ensure that the directory tree isn't so deep that the Windows [file length limitation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-names-extensions-faq#1TC=windows-7) is exceeded.